# What were the 17 instances of Kirk traveling through time?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, captain-kirk

In the *Star Trek: Deep Space Nine* episode "Trials and Tribble-ations," we meet the agency of Temporal Investigations. They mention that Captain Kirk has traveled through time on at least seventeen instances. What were those instances? I can think of *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*, possibly *Generations*, and "The City on the Edge of Forever". What are the other examples?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The actual line from the episode is:

> LUCSLY: Seventeen separate temporal violations. The biggest file on record.

Importantly, a "violation" does not necessarily refer to an "instance of time travel"; indeed, Memory Alpha interprets this line to mean *17 specific actions taken in the course of time travel that violate temporal regulations* ([see the article on this episode, bottom on the "Trivia" section](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trials_and_Tribble-ations_(episode)#Trivia)). Presumably, multiple violations could be incurred during a single time travel incident, just as multiple real-world laws could be broken during a single bank robbery.

These are all the occasions I know of on which Kirk traveled through time:

- "[The Naked Time](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Naked_Time_(episode))": The *Enterprise* is accidentally sent a few days backwards in time by the gravity well of a collapsing planet. Unclear if any "violations" were committed.
- "[Tomorrow is Yesterday](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tomorrow_is_Yesterday_(episode))": The *Enterprise* passed too close to a "black star" and is thrown back to 1969 where they encounter the US air force. [Many violations likely committed.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/153543/12857)
- "[The City On The Edge of Forever](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_City_on_the_Edge_of_Forever_(episode))": The Guardian of Forever sends Kirk, Spock and Bones back to the 1930's where McCoy severely alters history. Kirk endeavors to "correct" history, but hits a few bumps along the way.
- "[Assignment: Earth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Assignment:_Earth_(episode))": Kirk is sent back to 1969 by Starfleet to monitor Earth's history, but ends up interfering with history when he discovers that aliens are meddling in Earth's politics.
- "[All Our Yesterdays](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Our_Yesterdays_(episode))": Kirk, Spock and Bones are accidentally sent back into the history of the planet Sarpedion. Unclear if any violations are committed.
- "[Yesteryear](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Yesteryear_(episode))": Kirk enters the Guardian of Forever to observe the birth of the Orion civilization. Unclear if any violations are committed. Spock goes back in time to save his own life, which sounds like interfering with the past to me, and he was under Kirk's command at the time.
- "[Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home)": despite saving the Federation in the process, taking creatures (including a human!) from the 20th century to the present probably constitute violations.
- "[Star Trek: Generations](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Generations)": Kirk travels 80 years into the future by entering the Nexus. Unlikely that any violations were committed considering that he traveled into the future, not the past.

Additionally, while it's a bit of a stretch, Kirk existed at an accelerated time rate in "[Wink of an Eye](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Wink_of_an_Eye_(episode))", and in "[The Counter Clock Incident](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Counter-Clock_Incident_(episode))" the *Enterprise* enters a universe where time runs backwards and the crew (including Kirk) are de-aged.

Comment: It should be noted that "Assignment: Earth" was a Starfleet sanctioned trip and that Kirk didn't travel into the past himself in "Yesteryear", only Spock.  But you're right, probably multiple violations per instance.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt, At least per the [description of Yesteryear on Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Yesteryear_(episode)), Kirk was traveling through time at the beginning of the episode. Thus, it does count as an episode where Kirk travels in time. However, as you mentioned, Kirk did not travel with Spock later in the episode when Spock additionally traveled back to his own childhood.

Comment: "(including a human!)" why is that particularly significant? I'd have thought de-extincting (is that a word?) an intelligent race was more significant.

Comment: Also, we don't see every minute of his life. There are assuredly plenty of untelevised adventures.

Comment: @tardigrade it's more significant with regards to it's effect in the past, not the future.

Comment: Incidentally, the "black star" is called that because the term "black hole" only became popular later in 1967 (when the episode was made).

Comment: I stand corrected, Makyen.  Haven't seen TAS that many times.

Comment: Re: The Voyage Home, they also introduce the science behind transparent aluminium to the 20th century, that's got to be a violation.

Comment: @FacticiusVir Possibly not - it's canonicity is unclear, at best, but in the novelisation of Voyage Home Scotty says that he recognises the man giving them the tour as the inventor of transparent aluminium. The Temporal Investigators in the DS9 episode refer to the defence of a "Predestination paradox" (and that they hate them). Possibly Scotty used such an argument in his defence.

Comment: Follow-up question: was Janeway even worse (I think there's some quip about it "Voyager appears too often" by 27th c. crew)? Where does Archer fit in?

Comment: @NickT Janeway is almost certainly a worse offender than Kirk *based on what we see in screen*, but she got 7 years of screen time while Kirk only got 3 (plus the movies). Would make for a good question!

Comment: @NickT, keep in mind that Lucsly is part of the 24th Century Temporal Investigations authority, whereas Daniels was part of a 31st Century organization and the Aeon was apparently from the 29th Century.  As for Archer, it's unclear to me how much if anything Archer told his superiors about Daniels, and even if he gave a full report Lucsly might not have had a need-to-know.  Although I guess it is plausible to suppose that Archer's reports were what inspired the founding of Temporal Investigations in the first place!

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish, eyeballing the Memory Alpha page on time travel I only see two significant instances involving Janeway?  Granted the second one was a major offence.  I second the thought that this would make an interesting question.

Comment: Does "The counterclock incident" really count?

Comment: If you include the non canon novels, it's a hell of a lot more than 17. He travels to Sarpeidon's past at least twice more in a couple of them.

Comment: I doubt that any actions taken on Sarpeidon would count as violations because with the star exploding any changes to the past there would dead-end.

Comment: [Strange New Worlds "Tomorrow and Tomorrow and Tomorrow"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt18969462/) can be added to the list of time travel incidents now, although not "violations."

Answer (score 1):

They must be including events of some of the Novels.  In Yesterdays Son they travel back in time to the same world as in All Our Yesterdays.  In the novel Time for Yesterday they one again go back to the past of the same planet.  There is Killing Time, where Kirk from an alternate changed timeline go back with Spock and others to stop Romulans agents.  Also one where a speciies similar to the one introduced in voyager went back to stop the asterroid from wiping out the dinosaurs.

Comment: The novels have umpteen instances of Kirk traveling through time. Probably a hundred or more